# unkillable process caja waiting for "do_coredump"

Tags: 18.04, filesystem, system-monitor, kill, caja

So caja is unresponsive and I can't kill it in Ubuntu Mate 18.04. I took a screenshot showing what system monitor says about it. [image]

I tried killing it in the terminal with sudo kill 2719. I tried killing it in System Monitor. What do I do?

Comment: Try `killall -9 caja` or reboot.

Comment: ok tried it. It doesn't work.  Rebooting causes my system to hang during shutdown and the only way to proceed is a hard reset but then after I reboot within a day caja becomes unresponsive again so I really want to find a more elegant way to handle this without needing to hard reset.

Comment: Can you remember why Caja started to hang? Did you connected it to some network-drive or visited some folder with many images?

Comment: I'm certain I wasn't browsing a network.  I had it in dual pane mode and was browsing files considering the best way to organise them.  I think one of the drives is probably failing but that shouldn't permanently knock out my file manager, should it? It wasn't images - it was movies.

Comment: Previous versions of Nautilus and Caja have had problems with thumbnails. You can try to move thumbnails folder with `mv ~/.cache/thumbnails/ ~/.cache/thumbnails-old/` and then reboot.

Comment: like I said, when I try to reboot, it hangs and I'm forced to hard reset.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108391/discussion-between-user289455-and-n0rbert).